# How to pass event and id on onClick handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, event-handling, react-router-dom

In reality, I have a list of blogs, and each has its own unique ID. I want to get a specific blog's id on onclick and send it through navigate. The issue is that the page reloads when I click on the blog, which stops the request from being sent.
I simply need to know how to accomplish this.

Blogcard.jsx:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

    const BlogCard = ({ blogs }) => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
    
      const singleBlogHandler = async id => {
        const singleBlogDetail = await axios.get(
          `https://61791a83aa7f3400174047a6.mockapi.io/v1/GetBLogs/${id}`
        );
    
        navigate(`blogs/${id}`, { state: singleBlogDetail });
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          {blogs.map(blog => {
            return (
              <Stack
                key={blog.id}
                onClick={() => singleBlogHandler(blog.id)}
              >
                // Blog data is mapping here
              </Stack>
            );
          })}
        </>
      );
    };

export default BlogCard;
```

Comment: `onClick={(e) => singleBlogHandler(e, blog.id)}` and `const singleBlogHandler = async (e,id) => {....}` .... I'm not sure what is `Stack` component here, but you can check if `e.preventDefault()` works for page reload

Comment: Please edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]. You could also try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?